# I turned off some apps that were necessary, now things dont' work

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-3, system-apps

I have a Samsung Galaxy 3, around a year old.  Recently it started spontaneously rebooting all the time (like every ten minutes).  I looked on line for possible explanations, and found sites telling me to delete unnecessary apps that could cause it.

So I looked at what apps I'm running, found lots of things that I didn't know what they are, and turned some of them off.  And now - no surprise - things don't work right.  Symptoms:

- When I try to send messages, it (messages) sometimes (not always) immediately shuts down and I can't send them.  Sometimes (not always) I can't read them (beyond the first line that shows in the message list).
- I no longer have phone call logs - old logs are gone, new ones not created.
- I keep getting messages saying Touch Wiz Home is not working.  What is Touch Wiz Home?  It is on my list of "all apps" but not in the Running list, nor in the Turned Off list.  Same for TouchWiz easy home.  What is the difference between them?
- Almost ever time I get a call, it rings maybe once and then I get a message saying I missed the call.  (This may have been happening before as well - I don't get many calls, so I'm not sure.)

I assume I turned off things that I shouldn't have, but I don't know which things.  I don't know how to take screen shots on the phone and post them here, but here's a list of things that are turned off:

BadgeProvider

Best face

Blurb Checkout

Bubbles

CapabilityManagerService

ChatON

com.android.providers.partnerboo...

DirectConnectManager

DirectShareManager

Drive  (google drive)

Dropbox

Dual Clock (digital)

Favorite Contacts

Flipboard

Google Backup Transport

Google Calendar Sync

Google Contacts Sync

Google Play Games

Google Text-to-speech Engine

Group Play

InteractiveKeyguardTutorial

LogsProvider  (that sounded likely, I just turned it back on)

Market Feedback Agent

MobilePrintSvc_CUPS

MobilePrintSvc_CUPS_Backend

Multimedia UI Service Layer

S Memo

Samsung Link

Samsung Print Service Plugin

Samsung Push Service

Software Update

Story Album Widget

TalkBack

Trim

Weather (that's accuweather, which I thought I'd uninstalled - though it shows 0 
bytes, so maybe it's just an icon?)

Can anyone tell me what else I should turn back on to solve these problems?  it looks like logs might work again now that I turned it on.  I now have the logs predating when I started turning things off, though not those from the past week.  Progress, maybe?

Thank you!

catteau

p.s.  In the interim I put in a different battery, and I don't think I'm having the spontaneous reboot problem any more.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on all apps names Google

Favorite contacts

Story Album Widget

CapibiltyManagerService

Multimedia Ui Service layer

MobilePrintSvc_CUPS

MobilePrintSvc_CUPS_Backend

com.android.provider...

Comment: It says I shouldn't use comments for "thanks" - but  thank you, I appreciate your help!  (how come this forum doesn't want me to do that?)

Comment: @catteau not to be rude, but the idea is to keep chit chat that doesn't actually add anything to the discussion to a minimum. So if you find an answer helpful, upvote it, and if it solved your problem, mark it as accepted so if other people stumble on your question with the same problem, they will know how to solve their problem too.